# Ruby on rails tutorial section 7.2, my input fields are too small, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following along this Ruby on Rails [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-using_form_for) and after following the steps to complete the html and css for the sign up form I'm getting the first image below. The input text fields are much smaller compared to the second image which is what the tutorial shows I should get. Can someone explain how this can happen?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered out that Bootstrap generated the css for the input fields in the form `input[type="something"]`. This explains why using just `input` when specifying the css didn't work because the more specific css rule generated by Bootstrap would override mine.

```
/* line 59, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.0.4.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_forms.scss */
select, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime, [type="datetime-local"],
input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"],
input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 18px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #555555;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can happen because the pages are being displayed in different browsers, and even being displayed in the same one your font settings (size, default font family, etc.) could be different from the other one

Answer (score 0):

This happens with Bootstrap when you don't set the HTML5 doctype. Make sure you've got `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your layout, like in listing 7.1 of the tutorial.

What's happening there? I don't know what HTML5 feature is being used here, but Bootstrap assumes it's available. Your browser is treating the page as pre-5 HTML and doesn't render it correctly. So adding the doctype instructs the browser to act the way Bootstrap is expecting it to.

See the top of: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

Comment: This can't be it. The tutorial does use the HTML5 doctype, as seen in [the sample app reference implementation](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb).

Comment: @mhartl I referenced that in the answer. It was possible that the OP missed that while following the tutorial.